# displaying parameter of the string in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a string as
 "dbo.proudction @prodid= '1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3' ,@stock= 0”.

I have to execute a query

to select '1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3'.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to do:

```
SELECT @prodid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure of what you are looking for but could this be what you are looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE YourFieldName1 = @prodid and YourFieldName2 = @stock
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to extract the text between the quotes.

If the string in in a table you can do this

```
declare @T table(Col1 varchar(100))
insert into @T values ('dbo.proudction @prodid= ''1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3'' ,@stock= 0')

select 
  substring(Col1, Start, Stop-Start)
from @T
  cross apply 
    (select charindex('''', Col1)+1) c1(Start)
  cross apply
    (select charindex('''', Col1, Start)) c2(Stop)
```

Slightly modified if the string is in a variable.

```
declare @str varchar(100)
set @str = 'dbo.proudction @prodid= ''1,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,13,16,17,3'' ,@stock= 0'

select 
  substring(Col1, Start, Stop-Start)
from (select @str) as T(Col1)
  cross apply 
    (select charindex('''', Col1)+1) c1(Start)
  cross apply
    (select charindex('''', Col1, Start)) c2(Stop)
```

Comment: Thanks friends, really it helps me a lot.